# Правильно ли я понял как организовать базу данных?

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите как правильно организовать БД недвижимости. У нас есть здание и есть помещение.
Например высотка это здание, а квартиры в ней это помещения.
Бизнес-центр это здание, а офисы в нем это помещения
Вопрос как правильно организовать таблицы Т.к в одном здании может быть много помещений. Получается 2 таблицы.
**"Здания"** и **"Помещения"**. В помещения есть поле *зданиеID*.
Нужно ли хранить несколько *помещениеID* в таблице **"Здания"**?
У зданий есть несколько свойств. Например этажность и год постройки. Тут все просто. А как быть допустим с материалом стен. Кирпичный там или панельный ( список вариантов жестко ограничен во избежания "кирпич", "кирпичный", "КИРПИЧНЫЙ"). Нужна отдельная таблица **"Материал стен"** с списком значений? И в таблицу **"Здания"** нужно будет просто записать *материалСтенID*?
И подобных аналогов много.

Comment: *Нужно ли хранить несколько помещениеID в таблице "Здания"?* Нет. *Нужна отдельная таблица "Материал стен" с списком значений?* Да. *в таблицу "Здания" нужно будет просто записать материалСтенID?* Да. Но также и в таблице помещений может быть (а может и не быть) такое поле - например, в здании-монолите может быть кирпичная мансарда...

Comment: *Подскажите как правильно организовать БД недвижимости.* Изучите все материалы по термину "нормализация данных". Создавать структуру по некоему мистическому наитию. высматривая подробности на потолке - неблагодарное занятие, чреватое боком в будущем.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо! Я не совсем по наитию, я прочитал что мог просто нужно было подтверждение, правильно я понял или нет. Спасибо что ответили, я много где задавал вопрос, но ответили только тут.

Comment: Это девушка, а женщины априори не умеют работать с базами данных!

Comment: @ArtyMorris прошу прощенья, но Ваш ответ, я не очень точно помню, а он куда-то делся. Если у Вас есть совет или мнение, которое решит мою проблему, то я очень буду рад, его прочитать. Однако ответ Akina мне помог.